# Python ctypes OSError: [WinError 1114] Dynamic-link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm trying to call C++ functions using the `ctypes` library in Python:

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *
from random import randint

tester = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.dll')
print(tester.test(randint(1, 100)))
```

test.cpp

```cpp
#include <vector>

int cppTest(int num) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(num);
    return v.back();
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int test(int num) {
    return cppTest(num);
}
```

Then exuecute the following commands:

```
> g++ -o test.dll -shared -fPIC test.cpp
> python test.py
```

And I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    tester = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.dll')
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 1114] Dynamic-link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

I thought that using any of the C++ STL Libraries will cause the problem, so I tried using `new int` and the same error occured once again.

My environment:

- Windows 10 x64
- Python 3.8.5 x64 (same problem with Python 3.6)
- TDM-GCC 9.2.0

Could anyone help me with this problem?

**EDIT:**
The compiled `dll` file is 64-bit, checked by running the following command on VS 2017:

```
E:\...\test>dumpbin /headers test.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.16.27044.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file test.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
              13 number of sections
        612A415D time date stamp Sat Aug 28 21:59:57 2021
          10B000 file pointer to symbol table
            6FA9 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
            2026 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Line numbers stripped
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   DLL
```

**EDIT 2:**
When I tried to use MinGW as the compiler, here again was an error:

```
E:\...\test>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    tester = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.dll')
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'E:\...\test\test.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Comment: And is the built dll 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: Sorry for the edit, but it's 64-bit.

Comment: FYI, your code works fine with no change with MS Visual Studio compiler.  The error you see is likely from failure to locate the C++ runtime library.